# Attribute Based Routing VS Convention Based Routing - Best Practice for ASP.net Core RESTful APIs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm an experienced .NET developer, making my first steps in .NET Core in the passed few days, more specific in building RESTful APIs using ASP.net Core.

I know there are 2 possible routing options - Convention Routing (traditional) vs the Attribute Based Routing (newer).

I've read that **the ASP.net core's development team recommendation is to use Attribute Based Routing for APIs** rather than the tradition Convention Based routing, which is more suitable for MVC applications.

I'd really like to understand - **Why**?

It seems that the attribute based routing makes us write more code ending up having the same behavior as the conventional routing.

Comment: where is this recommendation written, can you please share?

Comment: This question is primarily opinion based. Read the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing and choose the one that best serves your needs.

Comment: @emrenevayeshirazi - I've been watching a Pluralsight course by Kevin Dockx about building RESTful services using ASP.net core. The author of the course stated that there.

Comment: @Nkosi, I've read some articles about it already - including the one you sent. But still - if the team building the framework recommends something, I guess there's a reason behind it, unless it's for the sake of semantics only

Comment: @DotnetProg granted. but even though they recommend it, it is still an opinion. Here is one of the notes from the documentation `This example highlights a key programming difference between attribute routing and conventional routing. Attribute routing requires more input to specify a route; the conventional default route handles routes more succinctly. However, attribute routing allows (and requires) precise control of which route templates apply to each action.`

Comment: @DotnetProg if you don't need precise control of your routes for restful api then by all mean use convention-based routing. It all depends on your preference as both will still work. If the devs state it is a best practice then have at it. As to the Why, then the dev would have to be the ones who answer that.

Comment: @Nkosi I realize that you can do it either way and get the same results, and I also realize they probably work in identical (or almost identical) ways, just thought that there might be something else in Attribute Based routing besides of  accomplishing the same thing in a different way and a matter of personal flavor.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both options are valid. Following are some suggestions on when to use  each one. 
Consider choosing traditional routes when:

- You want centralized configuration of all your routes.
- You use custom constraint objects.
- You have an existing working application you don't want to change

Consider choosing attribute routes when:

- You want to keep your routes together with your action's code
- You are creating a new application or making significant changes to an 
  existing.
- You want to match route parameter names with an actual parameter of the method(action), this will make the route parameter more descriptive and omit the weird error where the route ID would not match and that usually happens because we didn't configure routing correctly and we were using asp.net default route.

But the reasons why many developers recommend the **`Attribute Routes`** is because it allows you quite a bit more flexibility and places the routes next to the actions that will actually use them. 
You can switch from option to another at any time is not difficult